# Jmeter - while loop condition won't exit

Tags: javascript, while-loop, jmeter

Attempting to build in a little loop control to a script to prevent it infinite looping (because unfortunately, that is a serious possibility in the SUT)

I have two things which I'm interested in:
state - 'Complete' is the desired state
loopcount - it shouldn't take more than about 10 loops to complete

I am retrieving 'state' successfully from a JSON extractor and have defined 'loopcount' as a Counter element within the While controller.
Both are successfully retrieving their relevant information.

Problem I have is my javascript condition in the While controller, it keeps looping. This is my code:

```
${__javaScript("${state}"!="COMPLETE"||"${loopcounter}" < 10),)}
```

I want it to exit the loop when either state = Complete or loopcounter is more than 10 loops.

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In JavaScript [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) are case-sensitive so `Complete` and `COMPLETE` are different beasts
2. You don't need the quotation marks around the `${loopcounter}` variable
3. I also think you should replace `||` operator with `&&` operator

So amend your expression to look like:

```
 ${__javaScript(("${state}"!="Complete" && ${loopcounter} < 5),)}
```

See [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) article for more details.

Comment: Have amended my expression and it does now exit the loop, but now getting the following error:  ERROR o.a.j.f.JavaScript: Error processing Javascript [("PENDING"!="COMPLETE" && ${loopcounter} < 5)]

Comment: Most likely your `${loopcounter}` variable is not set or so

Comment: Following that I get javax.script.ScriptException: Expected ) but found { at line 1 column 27. Do I need to encapsulate the loopcounter section in ()?

Comment: Where is best to set the ${loopcounter} variable? I've got the loop counter element within the While loop, placing it outside stops the process working. Do I need to specify in my User Defined variables?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent Infinite looping you can add it under [`Runtime Controller`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) and write the maximum number of seconds .

You can check one part in While Controller 
 as `${__javaScript(${loopcounter} < 10),)}`

and add `If Controller` in Loop and check one part of the if as `${__javaScript("${state}"!="COMPLETE")}` and 
1. add `Test Action` to stop the Thread 
2. set loopcounter more than 10 and add `Test Action` to go to next loop iteration and also for it to fail loop

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- `loopCounter` should not be converted to string. So remove the double quotes around it
- You need a logical AND operator, not OR

This should do it:

```
"${state}" != "COMPLETE" && ${loopcounter} < 10
```

Comment: What's the best way to reset the counter back to 1 after each DO loop exits?